# make -j behaves differently with and without sub makes

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Can someone explain why make with sub-makes has different parallelization behavior?

I have two examples below. In one, all targets are in one Makefile where as in the second example each target has its own folder/makefile and they call each other using `$(MAKE)`.

Running them with `-j` produce outputs which are vastly different. In the first case, all access to the top-level dependency (`a.out` below) is synchronized. Make waits for the target to build before running any targets which depend on that.

In the second case, the top-level target (`a.out` below) is subjected to concurrent access. This causes serious problems for us unless we use our own synchronization techniques to overcome that.

Examples 1:

```
jesaremi@u16-3:~/maketest$ cat Makefile
.ONESHELL:

all:  d.out b.out c.out a.out

a.out: CALLER ?= self
a.out:
        @
        echo entering $@ "(called by $(CALLER))"
        sleep 10
        echo exiting $@

b.out:  a.out
        @
        echo entering $@
        sleep 1
        echo exiting $@

c.out: a.out
        @
        echo entering $@
        sleep 1
        echo exiting $@

d.out: a.out
        @
        echo entering $@
        sleep 1
        echo exiting $@

jesaremi@u16-3:~/maketest$ make
entering a.out (called by self)
exiting a.out
entering d.out
exiting d.out
entering b.out
exiting b.out
entering c.out
exiting c.out



jesaremi@u16-3:~/maketest$ make -j
entering a.out (called by self)
exiting a.out
entering d.out
entering c.out
entering b.out
exiting c.out
exiting d.out
exiting b.out
```

Example 2 (using sub-make):

```
jesaremi@js-u16-1:~/maketest$ cat */Makefile

---------- a/Makefile -------------
.ONESHELL:

a.out: CALLER ?= self
a.out:
        @
        echo entering $@ "(called by $(CALLER))"
        sleep 10
        echo exiting $@

---------- b/Makefile -------------
.ONESHELL:

export CALLER:=b

a.out:
        $(MAKE) -C ../a

b.out:  a.out
        @
        echo entering $@
        sleep 1
        echo exiting $@

---------- c/Makefile -------------
.ONESHELL:

export  CALLER:=c

a.out:
        $(MAKE) -C ../a

c.out: a.out
        @
        echo entering $@
        sleep 1
        echo exiting $@

---------- d/Makefile -------------
.ONESHELL:

export CALLER:=d

a.out:
        $(MAKE) -C ../a

d.out: a.out
        @
        echo entering $@
        sleep 1
        echo exiting $@


jesaremi@js-u16-1:~/maketest$ cat Makefile
all: d.out c.out b.out a.out

%.out:
        $(MAKE) -C $*

.PHONY:all



jesaremi@js-u16-1:~/maketest$ make
make -C d
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/d'
make -C ../a
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
entering a.out (called by d)
exiting a.out
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/d'
make -C c
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/c'
make -C ../a
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
entering a.out (called by c)
exiting a.out
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/c'
make -C b
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/b'
make -C ../a
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
entering a.out (called by b)
exiting a.out
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/b'
make -C a
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
entering a.out (called by self)
exiting a.out
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'





jesaremi@js-u16-1:~/maketest$ make -j
make -C d
make -C c
make -C b
make -C a
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/d'
make -C ../a
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/c'
make -C ../a
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/b'
make -C ../a
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
entering a.out (called by self)
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
entering a.out (called by c)
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
entering a.out (called by d)
entering a.out (called by b)
exiting a.out
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
exiting a.out
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
exiting a.out
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/c'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/d'
exiting a.out
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/a'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jesaremi/maketest/b'
```

Comment: We can't help because you've left out the most critical information: the contents of the root level makefile in the second example.  It's also hard to decipher the output of `cat */Makefile` because we don't know where one makefile ends and the next begins.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with a recursive use of `make`. It happens because in the second case each recipe prints several lines to the output.

Comment: @MadScientist I added the missing information

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in the 2nd example pay attention to the difference between the first execution (no -j) and the second execution (with -j). You should be able to clearly see that target a.out's recipe is printing intertwined because its called multiple time simulatneously

Comment: If you want multiple makefiles just for organization purposes, use `include`, and name them `something.make` rather than `Makefile`

Comment: @JeffSaremi Yep, and it should do the same thing for the non-recursive invocation too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking that recusive invocations of make communicate to each other *which* targets they are building and somehow interlock so that no two sub-makes are trying to build the same target at the same time.

That's nowhere close to something make can do.  All make can do is notify other sub-makes *how many* targets they are building so that you are ensured that no more than *N* total targets (for `-jN`) are invoked.

If you want to ensure that two different makefiles don't try to build the same target, that's up to you to do by organizing your makefiles; make can't do it for you.

In the second example, you list all the prerequisites as a single target:

```
all: d.out c.out b.out a.out
```

This recipe says, "before `all` can be built the targets `d.out`, `c.out`, `b.out`, and `a.out` must be finished".  This says *nothing* about the relative relationship between the prerequisites (`d.out`, `c.out`, `b.out`, or `a.out`) themselves so when you run with `-j` the sub-makes for all of them will be invoked at the same time.  If each of those tries to build the same shared target, then they will interfere with each other.

If you want to ensure that doesn't happen you must declare the prerequisite relationship in your makefile so make knows about it.  For example you could do this:

```
all: d.out c.out b.out a.out

d.out c.out b.out: a.out

%.out:
        $(MAKE) -C $*

.PHONY:all
```

Now, the recipes to build `d.out`, `c.out`, and `b.out` won't be started until after the recipe to build `a.out` is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation